# MySQL Inner Join - Not returning any results

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have two MySQL database tables called customers and orders, a sample is below...

```
customers
client_id | cust_name | cust_phone
--------------------------------
8273      | Mr Jones  | 382749584
38        | Mr Smith  | 773625372
9         | Mrs Brown | 922382938

orders
order_id | cust_id  | product_id
--------------------------------
392      | 9        | 9388
23       | 2837     | 9283
488      | 17       | 28392
```

I am trying to do an INNER JOIN like this...

```
SELECT * FROM customers
JOIN orders
ON customers.cust_id=orders.client_id
WHERE ('client_id' LIKE '9')
```

It is not returning any results but I am expecting it to show me the fields for the client_id of 9

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: try this one  `SELECT * FROM customers
JOIN orders
ON customers.cust_id=orders.client_id
WHERE orders.client_id =  9`

Comment: 'client_id' is a string. \`client_id\` is a column.

Comment: can you tell which answer is worked for you ?

Answer (score 3):

Your query is wrong.

```
SELECT * FROM customers
JOIN orders
ON customers.client_id =orders.cust_id
WHERE ('client_id' LIKE '9')
```

Column `client_id` doesn't exist in `orders` table. use `client_id = 9` instead of `like` query.

Answer (score 1):

i think you made mistake here 'client_id'

```
SELECT * FROM customers
JOIN orders
ON customers.cust_id=orders.client_id
WHERE client_id LIKE '9'
```

if you write '' it is take as string

Answer (score 0):

try this one for exact match

```
SELECT * FROM customers JOIN orders ON customers.cust_id=orders.client_id WHERE orders.client_id = 9
```

or for like

```
SELECT * FROM customers JOIN orders ON customers.cust_id=orders.client_id WHERE orders.client_id Like '9'
```

wild card characters can used here e.g.

```
'%9%' 
'9%'
```

Comment: like query will work.
client_id like 9
client_id like '9'